# jQuery 2.2 breaks my XHR re-write

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've got a fairly simple re-write of the native [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object that works fine with all versions of jQuery prior to 2.2. I'm trying to figure out what was changed in version 2.2 that broke it. I've looked every single commit in the [change log for version 2.2](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/) but could not find the cause.

When an AJAX request is made from the native API it works fine, when made by `$.ajax` (from jQ 2.2 or greater) the response is always `undefined`.

Here is a working fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/QADOKuxDvAhydrp46Bpk?p=preview

The demo fiddle includes the jQuery 2.2 as well as the previous version of jQuery in the comments for contrast.

Here's my XHR re-write..

```
/**
 * XHR Rewrite
 * 
 * This file attempts to overwrite the XMLHttpRequest object so custom hooks can 
 * be added, although the current code does not add any hooks or do anything
 * special. This is just to test that the XHR function can successfully be 
 * overridden.
 */

// save the native XHR method to xhrConstructor;
var xhrType = XMLHttpRequest ? "XMLHttpRequest" : "ActiveXObject";
var xhrConstructor = window[xhrType];

// now override the native method
window[xhrType] = function(){
    console.log("xhr: constructor");

    this._xhr = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(xhrConstructor, arguments));
    this.onreadystatechange = function(){};
    this.response = "";
    this.readyState = 0;
    this.responseText = "";
    this.responseType = 'text';
    this.responseURL = "";
    this.responseXML = null;
    this.status = 0;
    this.statusText = "";
    this.timeout = 0;
    this.withCredentials = false;

    var _this = this;
    this._xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        _this.getMockProperties();
        _this.onreadystatechange.apply(_this._xhr, arguments);
        _this.getMockProperties();
    };
};

window[xhrType].prototype.UNSENT = 0;
window[xhrType].prototype.OPENED = 1;
window[xhrType].prototype.HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2;
window[xhrType].prototype.LOADING = 3;
window[xhrType].prototype.DONE = 4;

window[xhrType].prototype.getMockProperties = function(){
    try{ this.response = this._xhr.response; }catch(e){}
    try{ this.readyState = this._xhr.readyState; }catch(e){}
    try{ this.responseText = this._xhr.responseText; }catch(e){}
    try{ this.responseURL = this._xhr.responseURL; }catch(e){}
    try{ this.responseXML = this._xhr.responseXML; }catch(e){}
    try{ this.status = this._xhr.status }catch(e){}
    try{ this.statusText = this._xhr.statusText; }catch(e){}
};

window[xhrType].prototype.setMockProperties = function(){
    try{ this._xhr.responseType = this.responseType; }catch(e){}
    try{ this._xhr.timeout = this.timeout; }catch(e){}
    try{ this._xhr.withCredentials = this.withCredentials; }catch(e){}
};

window[xhrType].prototype.abort = function(){
    console.log("xhr: abort");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.abort.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.getAllResponseHeaders = function(){
    console.log("xhr: getAllResponseHeaders");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.getAllResponseHeaders.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.getResponseHeader = function(){
    console.log("xhr: getResponseHeader");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.getResponseHeader.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.overrideMimeType = function(){
    console.log("xhr: overrideMimeType");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.overrideMimeType.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.setRequestHeader = function(){
    console.log("xhr: setRequestHeader");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.setRequestHeader.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.send = function(){ 
    console.log("xhr: send");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.send.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};

window[xhrType].prototype.open = function(){
    console.log("xhr: open");
    this.setMockProperties();
    var r = this._xhr.open.apply(this._xhr, arguments);
    this.getMockProperties();
    return r;
};
```

What changed in jQuery 2.2 that broke my code?

Comment: I wonder how many browsers in the wild here at the end of 2016 actually require "ActiveXObject".

Comment: Yeah well, one often does insane things when debugging, like support active x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with jQuery 2.2, they use the content-type header to determine the response's content type rather than the XMLHttpRequest.responseType.

The completed project is here, if anyone needs something similar: https://github.com/Pamblam/XHRCreep